# Reading (x,y) points from file to list in Python

Tags: python, file

I am trying to extract points from a file formatted like this

```
(311.7836  , -399.777),
(-238.3153 , -399.310),
(107.8696  , -398.783),
(188.6595  , -397.295)
```

and directly pass them to a list of points in my program like so :

```
pts = [
(311.7836  , -399.777),
(-238.3153 , -399.310),
(107.8696  , -398.783),
(188.6595  , -397.295)
]
```

So far I have tried :

```py
data = [line.strip() for line in open("myfile.txt", 'r')]
```

but i am getting :

```
['(311.7836, -399.777),', '(-238.3153, -399.310),', '(107.8696, -398.783),', '(188.6595, -397.295)']
```

Also I tried using `readline()` and `strip()` and other likewise approaches I found here but to no avail.
I am new to python thanks for the help.

Comment: @JohnColeman I fixed the typos, my problem are those intermediate { ' } characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `literal_eval` from the [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module:

```
import ast

with open("myfile.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.read().split(',\n')
    data = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in lines]

print(data)
```

With you sample data this prints:

```
[(311.7836, -399.777), (-238.3153, -399.31), (107.8696, -398.783), (188.6595, -397.295)]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
data = [(float(line.strip()[1:].split(',')[0]), float(line.strip()[1:].split(',')[1][:-1])) for line in open("myfile.txt", 'r')]
```

or if you prefer in multiple line :

```
data = []
for line in open("myfile.txt", 'r'):
    x = line.strip()[1:].split(',')
    data.append((float(x[0]), float(x[1][:-1])))
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you didn't handle the comma that's at the end of each line.

You can **`rstrip()`** it in the following way:

```
data = [line.rstrip(",") for line in open("myfile.txt", 'r')]
```

However, if you are planning to process those numeric pairs, you should create a list of tuples instead:

```
data = [eval(line.rstrip(",")) for line in open("myfile.txt", 'r')]
```

Note: try to avoid `eval()` as much as possible, I've used it for the sake of simplicity. Splitting the string and float-casting the values would be a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None).dropna(axis=1)
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip('()'))

   0            1
0  311.7836     -399.777
1  -238.3153    -399.310
2  107.8696     -398.783
3  188.6595     -397.295
```